# 400 (Bad request) error with jQuery POST to MVC3 app running in IIS 8

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, iis-8

As the title says, in my MVC3 app I am sending a POST request to a controller and getting a 400 error.

The request includes an id which the controller uses to retrieve the contents of a file and sends it back in a response.

I read through some relevant  stackoverflow posts that suggested it can be caused by hardcoded URL's, which I was using, but I have since used the URL helpers and continue to get this issue.

Here is my Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetContent(string id)
{
    // Decrypt string to get filepath.
    string file = EncryptStrings.DecryptAESString(id);

    string content = String.Empty;

    if(System.IO.File.Exists(file))
    {
        content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file);
    }

    return Content(content);
}
```

My jQuery code:

```
function setContent(id) {
    $.post('@Url.Action("GetContent", "Content")/' + id, null,
        function (data) {
            $('#article').html(data);
            bringToFront('article-container');
    }, 'text');
}
```

And an example of what the request looks like (I have increased the maxUrlLength to allow for the long requests):

```
http://localhost/KBLite/Content/GetContent/545E55A34A5B6EE892286D481D177C149A003AAA0F44FAAD432970A9BADA5B79713344D2D80580DCA3345D520742E358A2089BF2E01EA553203AFCA27C96B4150923D33EC57D93F55241F9398D217E3B38609449CB64DCD2D2C31C850E5EBB452CC5A8F3B2F71D0B30E282D16F394FDC60696C3661372B1D200AE1B45371473DD7DC077BEAE475CD7D498F0AEDD63727
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: do you have any special routes?

Comment: @achillesminor - Please see my edit to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to "[Understanding 400 Bad Request Exception](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2010/04/23/understanding-400-bad-request-exception.aspx)":

> Any individual path segment (the portion of the URL that does not
>   include protocol, server name, and query string, for example,
>   http://a.com/b/c?d=e,  here the b and c are individual path) must not
>   contain more than 260 characters. Also http.sys disallows URLs that
>   have more than 255 path segments.

I believe your id is being interpreted as a path segment and as a result this 400 response is occurring.  The `maxUrlLength` that you configured is only for the total url length, not a segment of it.

**Edit**: There is an easy fix for this.  Change your url to this:

```
http://localhost/KBLite/Content/GetContent?id=545E55A34A5B6EE892286D481D177C149A003AAA0F44FAAD432970A9BADA5B79713344D2D80580DCA3345D520742E358A2089BF2E01EA553203AFCA27C96B4150923D33EC57D93F55241F9398D217E3B38609449CB64DCD2D2C31C850E5EBB452CC5A8F3B2F71D0B30E282D16F394FDC60696C3661372B1D200AE1B45371473DD7DC077BEAE475CD7D498F0AEDD63727
```

Notice the `?id=`.  This will change the way your id is parsed internally in ASP.NET and it won't be treated as a path segment.